# How to make an add method to a Python class?

Tags: python

```
class FootMeasure(object):
    def __init__(self, feet=0, inches=0):
        """Initiates feet and inches to 0. User can enter custom numbers"""
        self.__feet = feet
        self.__inches = inches
    def __repr__(self):
        """Returns inches higher than 11 to a foot representation
           Returns 60 inches at 5 ft instead of 5 ft 0 inches
           Returns 0 as 0 ft 0 inches
        """
        if self.__inches == 0:
            return str(self.__feet) + ' ft '
        elif self.__inches > 11:
           feet = int(self.__inches / 12)
           remainder = self.__inches % 12
           return str(feet) + ' ft ' + str(remainder) + ' in '
        else: 
            return str(self.__feet) + ' ft. ' + str(self.__inches) + ' in. '
    def __add__(self):
        """Returns two FootMeasures added together"""
```

I am new to classes so I am a bit confused on how to do this. I know it is probably some simple process but I am only finding examples on adding fractions and can't figure it out. So, how would I make an add method for this? For instance if I said first = FootMeasure(1,1) and second = FootMeasure(1,1). Then result = first + second. And I of course wanted the result of 2 ft 2 in. How could I do this?

Comment: How would you do it if there weren't any classes involved, and you just took two `(feet, inches)` pairs? Do that, but call it `__add__(self, other)`, make it take FootMeasures as self and other, and build a FootMeasure instead of a tuple as the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two arguments, `self` and `other`. Then for each new attribute you just add the attribute of `self` and `other` together. Create and return a new `FootMeasure` object with those new values, and you're all set!

```
def __add__(self, other):
    """Returns two FootMeasures added together"""
    return FootMeasure(self.__feet + other.__feet,
                       self.__inches + other.__inches)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__add__` method should take two arguments: one for the object itself, and one for the other one. Then add the appropriate values together and `return` the result.

However, I would recommend refactoring your code to store a `FootMeasure` object as a single number of inches. You can then do calculations much more easily. This is similar to how currency calculations are handled, with values represented by a single integer of the smallest denomination (e.g. $3.50 would be represented as 350 cents).

Also, an object's `__repr__` is supposed to allow you to reproduce the object, in a way that `eval()` can handle. You can use the built-in `divmod()` to produce the quotient and remainder, then unpack it for the format string.

Finally, this class would do well with other methods for a nicely-formatted string (`__str__`, the contents of which you had in `__repr__`), the object's feet, the object's inches (inches under 12 taking feet into account, not total inches, as that's already `inches`), and so on.

```
class FootMeasure(object):
    def __init__(self, feet=0, inches=0):
        """Initiates feet and inches to 0. User can enter custom numbers"""
        self.inches = feet*12 + inches
    def __repr__(self):
        """Returns the string representation of the object, in feet and inches
        """
        return 'FootMeasure({}, {})'.format(*divmod(self.inches, 12))
    def __add__(self, other):
        """Returns two FootMeasures added together"""
        return FootMeasure(inches=self.inches + other.inches)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two arguments:

```
def __add__(self, other):
```